# Compass Vertical Rhythm

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I have a `<tr>` with 4 `<th>`'s inside and without borders the `<tr>` and `<th>`'s are all 22 pixels tall which equals my `$base-line-height` - Perfect.

However, when I add `+horizontal-borders(1px, 0)` the `<th>`'s show up as 23 pixels tall and knock my vertical rhythm out.

Why is this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vertical-rhythms approach uses padding in combination with borders to keep the rhythm consistent. If you set the second argument (lines) to zero, there is no room for vertical-rhythms to work. The rhythm lines argument has to be greater than the border width.

Comment: If I set lines to one then I get a border, pretty much one lines worth of padding, my text line, another line of padding and then the border. How can I use this whilst minimising the line of padding, I pretty much just need border, text and border, very small amount of padding. I can have padding, just not 1 lines worth. But yes, it does explain what is going on. Any solutions?

Comment: You can use fractions of lines. I often use `.5` or even `.25`. I think 0.13 will allow you to use margins instead of padding to complete a line. You can also add the borders by hand and use `-1px` margins to balance them out.

Comment: Thanks. So is 0.13 a special value that uses margin instead then?

Comment: I'm not sure. I thought I saw a commit for it, but I'm not seeing that now. I may add the feature myself, as it's a common request.